# How to change style for ttk OptionMenu including the dropdown selection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk, ttkwidgets

I want to edit the font of the OptionMenu including the dropdown selection, but I don't know how to do that for the dropdown selection.

I tried to change the ttk style, but that only affects the main button, not the dropdown selection.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

# style changes
style = ttk.Style()
style.configure(".", font=("Arial", 20)) # larger font for everything
style.configure("TMenubutton", background="darkgray") # background for menubutton 

menu = ttk.OptionMenu(root, tk.StringVar(), "North", *["North", "East", "South", "West"])
menu.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

With the following result:
[OptionMenu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqnD4.png)

Comment: You can set the background color of the dropdown menu as mentioned in the comment of the answer in the duplicate question.